# converting a multidimentional JSON array to JS variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

imagine you have the following JSON:

```
{"zero":{"0":"foo","1":"foo2"},"one":"fooa","two":"foob"}
```

What is the most efficient way to convert it to :

```
 var zero = ['foo','foo2'];
 var one = 'fooa';
 var two = 'foob';
```

Comment: Probably start off by changing it to: `var obj = {"zero":["foo","foo2"],"one":"fooa","two":"foob"}` And then be all like `obj.zero` or `obj.one` or `obj.two`

Comment: Why do you want to use variables when you've got everything nicely organized in a data structure?

Comment: Because I want to convert this to HTML

Comment: @PedroEsperança: That doesn't really make sense. What does HTML have to do with your data references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var json = '{"zero":{"0":"foo","1":"foo2"},"one":"fooa","two":"foob"}';
var pJson = JSON.parse(json);
var zero = [ pJson.zero[0], pJson.zero[1] ];
var one = pJson.one;
var two = pJson.two;
```

Comment: could you help me visualize how to integrate this with a while? So that we can create an function that can do this to any kind of multidimensional array